# Having trouble getting simple single-user Twitter automation Ruby script working with Oauth

Tags: ruby, oauth, twitter

I am trying to build some simple Ruby scripts to run on a local machine and automate some Twitter functions, for my own use only. I am having difficulty getting OAuth authorization to work.

I registered the application at http://dev.twitter.com/apps and retrieved its consumer key and secret, and I retrieved the access token and access secret for my Twitter account from http://dev.twitter.com/apps/<application_id>/my_token

Boiling it down to the minimum code:

```
require 'oauth'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "my application's consumer key"
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "my application's consumer secret"
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'my access token'
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET = 'my access secret'
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  { :site => "http://api.twitter.com",
    :scheme => :header
  })
token_hash = { :oauth_token => TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
               :oauth_token_secret => TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET
             }
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash )
response = access_token.request(:get, "http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?user_id=Mashable")
puts response.body
```

Gets me the following every time.

> {"error":"This method requires authentication.","request":"\/1\/friends\/ids.json?user_id=Mashable"}

So it appears that Twitter is not recognizing that the authorization has taken place. I can't figure out why. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the verifier pin with your request? Most OAuth API's only require the verifier to get the access token. Twitter's API uses the verifier for every API request.